# Invoking shell script from a python script using root privileges

Tags: python, linux, shell, root, sudo

I'm trying to invoke a shell script `shell_script.sh` from a python script (`python_script.py`) using the call command. The `shell_script.sh` invokes a executable that requires root access to execute.

The `python_script.py` invokes `shell_script.sh` using `subprocess.call()`.

See below: 
`subprocess.call(['/complete_path/shell_script.sh', 'param1', 'param2',
'param3'], shell=True)`

When I try to execute the python script `python_script.py` it gives me permission denied.

I've tried different ways.

a) Invoke python with sudo - `sudo python python_script.py`

b) Invoke sudo into inside the call method - `subprocess.call(['sudo' '/complete_path/shell_script.sh', 'param1', 'param2',
'param3'], shell=True`)

What's the best way to resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put logic in the `python_script.py` to check its UID and fail if is not executed as root.  `if os.getuid() != 0:`.  That will ensure it only runs as root, ether by a root login, or sudo.

If you're getting permission denied when trying to execute the `python_script.py`, you need to set the execute bit on it. `chmod +x python_script.py`